# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set!

Tags: kali

I installed Hyprland. But after login to my Xfce DE I tried to start TTY. But TTY doesn't start. When I tried to start Hyprland I got the error message showing below:

[CRITICAL] Critical error thrown: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set!
zsh: IOT instruction  Hyprland

Comment: You tagged "Kali". Note that Kali Linux is out of scope on this site. Then you do not provide more detail on your system. How did you try to start TTY? How did you try to start Hyprland? How did you install Hyprland in the first place? Through APT? Manual compiling? Provide more detail in your question: use "edit". A typical procedure to start Hyprland would be by choosing the session from the login screen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.